# Is this a type annotation, an object, or something else?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was looking at [this code example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) and stumbled upon this syntax:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const PrivateRoute = ({component:Component, ...rest}) => (
//(...)
  <Component {...props} />
// (...)
);
```

I'm confused about the `:Component` part. This looks like a static type annotation and sort of behaves like a generic one, yet this is Javascript so it can only be an object, right? If this is an object, does that mean the function is assigning a default, empty Component object to its own parameters? If so, how is it able to receive it from the caller, e.g. (as per the example):

```
<PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={Protected} />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is named object [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) from ES6. Below

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component:Component, ...rest}) => (
```

means that whatever will be passed to `PrivateRoute` as `component` property, one can use it using the `Component` variable.

Comment: This would surely conflict with Typescript?

Comment: @murat no, the typescript annotation comes after the object, `{ a: b } : { a: type }`. And yes, that is confusing (thats why I originally dupevoted this for the wrong thing)

Comment: In Typescript you would use ({component: Component, ...rest}: {component: Component, rest: any})

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks. This is actually quite useful for ReactJs.

Comment: So `Component` here is just an arbitrary variable name? It's not the React object Component?

Comment: @Asik Yes it is just arbitrary name. But due to React conventions apparently one wants to pass a component to `component` property, hence the use of capital name in the name: `Component`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confused about the :Component part. This looks like a static type annotation

Yup it *looks like* because the name of the global `Component` class was shadowed, therefore it looks like if `component` is typed with a Typescript annotation as a `Component`. However in Typescript the type would follow the object literal, so it would be:

```
 ({ component: Component, ...rest }: { component: Component, rest: any })
```

So actually the first `Component` is the name of the destructured variable while the second `Component` types `component` as a Component. I would definetly rename the inner variable to something more meaningful and to prevent shadowing:

```
 ({ component: ChildComponent, ...rest }) => (
   //...
   <ChildComponent {...props} />
)
```

That would equal:

```
 props => {
  const ChildComponent = props.component,
      rest = props;

  return <ChildComponent {...rest}/>
 };
```

> If this is an object, does that mean the function is assigning a default, empty Component object to its own parameters?

No, a default value would follow an `=` e.g.:

```
 ({ component: ChildComponent = DefaultComponent, ...rest }) =>
```